# How does one replace/fill an entire blank html page with DOMParser output?

Tags: javascript, domparser, document.write

I have this code:

```
   function pagereplace(){
      const parser=new DOMParser();
      const adocument=parser.parseFromString(somevariable, "text/html");
    };
```

`somevariable` contains the complete html source of a webpage (including doctype and all html tags, etc.) as a string.
I have searched and searched for ways to fill up a (totally blank, no html tags whatsoever, not even a doctype) page with `adocument`. I realize I could just do `document.write(somevariable)`, but this is widely frowned upon. Are there any good genuine replacements for `document.write` here that can fill up the completely blank page I have specifically with `adocument`?

Comment: First question is why are you needing to do this in the first place? Why can't you serve this from server? In my many years of web development have never run into such a use case

Comment: I don't control the server.

Comment: But you can request the content from your server.

Comment: What do you mean? As I've said, I don't control the server. This is front-end only.